# Header arguments for emacs-jupyter

Tags: org-mode, babel, jupyter

The following example uses `emacs-jupyter`. I'm happy with the result (i.e. display inside emacs, and export to LaTeX), but I'm unhappy that the second and the third code block use different header arguments.

The second code block (a math equation) results in 1) a png, if displayed inside emacs, and 2) LaTeX code, if exported to LaTeX, which is great. Unfortunately these header arguments do not work for the third code block (a simple plot). Hence I use different header arguments for the third code block, as you can see below.

It feels cumbersome to use different header arguments depending on whether the result of the code block is a math equation or a plot. Is it possible to rewrite the header arguments such that they can be used for both the second *and* the third code block?

```
#+begin_src jupyter-python :results none :exports none
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(latex_mode='equation*')
x = sp.Symbol('x')
#+end_src

#+begin_src jupyter-python :results value :exports both :display (if (eq org-export-current-backend 'latex) "text/latex" "image/png")
sp.Integral(x**2, x)
#+end_src

#+begin_src jupyter-python :results output :exports both :display image/png
sp.plot(x**2)
#+end_src
```